# Java System.out.println after reading from HashMap

Tags: java

The following is my code:

```
public void serialize() throws IOException {
    if(this.DO.size()==0){
        return;
    }
    for(Map.Entry<SearchKey,Float>set:DO.entrySet()){
        SearchKey key = set.getKey();
        float dist = set.getValue();
        long code = key.mc;
        char level = key.level;
        System.out.println(code);
        System.out.println(level);
        System.out.println(dist);
    }

}
```

The dataset has 4 elements:

```
274672398340,10,561.53235
1125058143634206,13,68.06594
1125058143634189,13,18.427612
1125058143634204,13,86.49355
```

where the first entry is the key and the middle entry is the level and the last entry is the distance. When I used Intelijj debugger, I found code, level and dist actually have the right values, but when I use the print statement, I got the following:

```
274672398340


561.53235
1125058143634206

68.06594
1125058143634189

18.427612
1125058143634204

86.49355
```

Does anyone know what may cause this error? Thanks.

Comment: What output do you expect? And why isn't each number on a separate line? Are you running the code in your question?

Comment: By the way, let me remind you that `char`/`Character` has been legacy since Java 5, essentially broken since Java 2. As a 16-bit type, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.  

I suggest defining your field with a different data type.

Comment: Hello thank you. Yes I ran the code. It was supposed to print out a total of 12 numbers each at a separate line. But here some numbers are missing. I feel the answer below helps. Also thank you Basil for this reminder. I actually did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `char level = key.level;`.

Since you have a `char` data type, `System.out.println()` prints a character instead of a number, i.e. the number is interpreted as ASCII code. ASCII code `10` is `LINE FEED`, code `13` is `CARRIAGE RETURN` - that's why you see those newlines.

Try to cast the `char` to `int` when printing:

```
System.out.print((int) level);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Good catch, and a good Answer. An even better solution might be avoiding the use of the `char` as the type of `key.level`.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is solved. And I will try to switch to short now. I was too greedy to try to save this 1 byte between char and short because I know my level is at most 20.